# Не могу правильно обновить данные сущности

Tags: c#, entity-framework, update

Не могу правильно обновить сущность, постояннно выскакивает исключение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The instance of entity type 'Inventory' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Inventid'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

Что делаю не так, тоже понять не могу, обычный метод `Update()` не работает!

```
var id = context.Inventories.Where(x => x.Inventid == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString()))
    .Select(z => z.Inventid).FirstOrDefault();
var fil = context.Filials.Where(x => x.Filialname == cbxFilial.Text)
    .Select(z => z.Filialid).FirstOrDefault();
var invttype = context.Inventtypes.Where(x => x.Inventname == cbxTypename.Text)
    .Select(z => z.Inventtypeid).FirstOrDefault();
var cabinet = context.Cabinets.Where(x => x.Cabinetname == cbxCabnum.Text)
    .Select(z => z.Cabinetid).FirstOrDefault();
var service = context.Services.Where(x => x.Servicename == cbxService.Text)
    .Select(z => z.Serviceid).FirstOrDefault();
var status = context.Statuses.Where(x => x.Statusname == cbxStatus.Text)
    .Select(z => z.Statusid).FirstOrDefault();

Inventory inv = new()
{
    Inventid = id,
    Inventname = tbxName.Text,
    Serialnum = tbxSerialnum.Text,
    Datepov = dtpDatepov.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Datenextpov = dtpDatenextpov.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Filialid = (int)fil,
    Inventtype = invttype,
    Cabinetid = cabinet,
    Serviceid = service,
    Statusid = status,
    Yearofman = dtpYearOfMan.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime()
};

context.Entry(inv).State = EntityState.Modified;

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: добавьте `context.Inventories.Attach(inv);` сразу после инициализации `inv`

Comment: если не поможет, тут есть похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/a/42475617/312041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Да, надо приаттачить новый элемент.
2. Такое

   ```
   var id = context.Inventories.Where(x => x.Inventid == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString()))
       .Select(z => z.Inventid).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

   везде заменить на такое

   ```
   var id = context.Inventories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Inventid == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString()))?.Inventid;
   ```

Должно быть как-то так:

```
var fil = context.Filials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Filialname == cbxFilial.Text)?.Filialid;
var invttype = context.Inventtypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Inventname == cbxTypename.Text)?.Inventtypeid;
var cabinet = context.Cabinets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Cabinetname == cbxCabnum.Text)?.Cabinetid;
var service = context.Services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Servicename == cbxService.Text)?.Serviceid;
var status = context.Statuses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Statusname == cbxStatus.Text)?.Statusid;

// тут проверить, что полученные значения не null
Inventory inv = new()
{
    Inventname = tbxName.Text,
    Serialnum = tbxSerialnum.Text,
    Datepov = dtpDatepov.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Datenextpov = dtpDatenextpov.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Filialid = (int)fil,
    Inventtype = (int)invttype,
    Cabinetid = (int)cabinet,
    Serviceid = (int)service,
    Statusid = (int)status,
    Yearofman = dtpYearOfMan.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime()
};

context.Inventories.Attach(inv);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

P.S. Кстати, чтобы не заниматься такими безобразиями

```
var fil = context.Filials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Filialname == cbxFilial.Text)?.Filialid;
```

, нужно в ComboBox'ы набивать пары значений (id, name):

```
public struct stIntStr {
    public stIntStr(int i, string s) { Value = i; Name = s; }
    public int Value { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

cbxFilial.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbxFilial.ValueMember = "Value";
cbxFilial.DataSource = context.Filials.Select(s => new stIntStr(s.Filialid, s.Filialname)).ToList();
//  а потом в new
Filialid = (int)cbxFilial.SelectedValue,
```

Comment: К сожалению, теперь сразу вылетает исключение
 var id = context.Inventories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Inventid == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString())).Inventid;
                ...
 Inventory inv = new()
{
 Inventid = id,
                    Inventname = tbxName.Text,
                    ...
                    Statusid = status,
                    Yearofman = dtpYearOfMan.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime()
                };
context.Inventories.Attach(inv);
context.Entry(inv).State = EntityState.Modified;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: Какое исключение? В каком месте?

Comment: Кстати, предполагаю, что Inventid может быть уникальным ключём в таблице, поэтому второе такое же добавить нельзя. Если так, то он, скорее всего, генерируется автоматически, и Inventid = id нужно исключить из new. Ну, и первая строка тогда ненужна

Comment: в том же месте, переписал поле id, и добавил аттач в конце

Comment: В том же в каком же? Аттач нужно вставить вместо context.Entry(inv).State = EntityState.Modified

Comment: да , вы правы, это уникальный ключ, но если удалить его 


System.InvalidOperationException: "The property 'Inventory.Inventid' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property."
Получается теперь вот такое исключение

Comment: да, код рабочий, но он буквально добавляет новую запись в таблицу, как я понял, из-за того что поле id является уникальным - его нельзя редактировать?

Comment: Если поле д. б. уникальным, то это не значит, что его нельзя редактировать. Но почти всегда уникальное поле генерируется автоматически для гарантированного обеспечения его уникальности, и в этом случае (автогенерации) его редактировать нельзя (по-моему, где-то есть какие-то исключения, но это не для общего случая)

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то это будет полезно, проблема решилась вот так:

```
var fil = context.Filials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Filialname == cbxFilial.Text)?.Filialid;
var invttype = context.Inventtypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Inventname == cbxTypename.Text)?.Inventtypeid;
var cabinet = context.Cabinets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Cabinetname == cbxCabnum.Text)?.Cabinetid;
var service = context.Services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Servicename == cbxService.Text)?.Serviceid;
var status = context.Statuses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Statusname == cbxStatus.Text)?.Statusid;

Inventory inv = new()
{
    Inventname = tbxName.Text,
    Serialnum = tbxSerialnum.Text,
    Datepov = dtpDatepov.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Datenextpov = dtpDatenextpov.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime(),
    Filialid = (int)fil,
    Inventtype = (int)invttype,
    Cabinetid = (int)cabinet,
    Serviceid = (int)service,
    Statusid = (int)status,
    Yearofman = dtpYearOfMan.Value.Date.ToUniversalTime()
};
context.Inventories.Update(inv);
DeletingWithoutDialog();
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Метод `DeletingWithoutDialog()` вылядит так:

```
public async void DeletingWithoutDialog()
{
    InvDbContext db = new InvDbContext();         
    //получение  ID  прибора
    var p = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());
    //Выбор по ID
    Inventory? inv = db.Inventories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Inventid == p);
    if (inv != null)
    {
        db.Remove(inv);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Суть проблемы на самом деле в том, что `EF` отслеживает сущности и у вас получается две сущности с одним `Id` - та, которую `EF` прочитал из базы, и ваша новая сущность. Так делать нельзя. Правильно это решается одним из двух способов:

1. Берёте из `EF` старую сущность с этим `Id`, меняете ей поля на нужные значения и сохраняете её.
2. Добавляете в `EF` новую сущность с **другим** `Id`.

Просто определитесь, что же вы хотите: обновить имеющуюся сущность или добавить новую.

Comment: Верно подмечено, но хочется уточнить: для редактирования берёте запись var inv = context.Inventories.First(x => x.Inventid == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString())), а потом меняете ей поля и делаете Update; для создания новой записи - как в ответе. А можно редактировать прямо в DataGridView, а чтобы там был текст, а не id, нужно выбрать тип колонки - ComboBox, и в него добавить пары значений id, text